# not a Group by expression error in cursor but not in select maybe because of date?

Tags: oracle, plsql, group-by, cursor

I'm trying to execute the block below in Oracle PL/SQL:

```
declare
    cursor c1 is
        select cod_art, to_number(to_char(fecha, 'q')) fech, sum(unidades) suma 
        from tventas  
        group by cod_art, to_number(to_char(fecha, 'q'))
        order by cod_art;    
begin
    for i in c1 loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i.fech);
    end loop;
end;
```

If I run the `select` of the cursor on its own, everything is okay, but when I run the whole block it throws an error *"not a group by expression"*.

```
Informe de error -
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
ORA-06512: at line 3
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

I tried removing `"to_number(to_char(...)"` and it works, also I found out that if I remove the for loop it runs too but none of these results are what I need, I comment them just because I suppose that it can help. Any idea?

Test data setup:

```
create table tventas(
   cod_art number(4),
   fecha date,
   unidades number(4)
);

insert into tventas values (0001, date '2012-01-01', 100);
insert into tventas values (0001, date '2012-02-02', 10);
insert into tventas values (0001, date '2012-10-10', 30);
insert into tventas values (0002, date '2012-06-06', 200);
insert into tventas values (0002, date '2012-06-06', 40);
insert into tventas values (0002, date '2012-12-12', 50);
```

Comment: Works for me with a dummy `tventas` table.

Comment: I have it exactly like you edited, "don´t" was a mistake when someone edited it. It still doesn´t working in my table tventas and i dont know why, but the error report is exactly this: Informe de error -
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
ORA-06512: at line 3
ORA-06512: at line 8
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Can you post a sample `create table` and data that reproduces the issue?

Comment: of course, heres is my create table: create table tventas( cod_art number(4) references tarticulos, fecha date, unidades number(4) );

Comment: here my rows: insert into tventas values (0001, '1/1/2012', 100); insert into tventas values (0001, '2/2/2012', 10); insert into tventas values (0001, '10/10/2012', 30); insert into tventas values (0002, '6/6/2012', 200); insert into tventas values (0002, '6/6/2012', 40); insert into tventas values (0002, '12/12/2012', 50);

Comment: It works fine for me with that data (Oracle 12.1, though I don't see any version-specific features).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is code you ran? Because, it won't compile. There's no `don't` in Oracle.

Anyway: I rewrote it in order to be able to run it on Scott's EMP table - works just fine:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     CURSOR c1
  3     IS
  4          --        SELECT cod_art,
  5          --               TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (fecha, 'q')) fech,
  6          --               SUM (unidades) suma
  7          --          FROM tventas
  8          --      GROUP BY cod_art, TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (fecha, 'q'))
  9          --      ORDER BY cod_art;
 10          SELECT ename cod_art,
 11                 TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (hiredate, 'q')) fech,
 12                 SUM (sal) suma
 13            FROM emp
 14        GROUP BY ename, TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (hiredate, 'q'))
 15        ORDER BY ename;
 16  BEGIN
 17     FOR i IN c1
 18     LOOP                                       --> LOOP, not "don't"
 19        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (i.fech);
 20     END LOOP;
 21  END;
 22  /
1
1
2
2
4
4
2
4
3
1
4
4
3
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Consider posting code that you really use, possibly the way I did it, in SQL*Plus so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded.

Comment: I did not use don't, it was a mistake when someone  edited it.  My code is exactly like it is right now. Unfortunately it still doesn't work and throws this: Informe de error -
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
ORA-06512: at line 3
ORA-06512: at line 8
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I've seen comments under your question; William didn't face any problem either. Seriously, consider posting copy/paste of your SQL*Plus session, **exactly** like I did it.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace TYPE TOTAL_TRIM AS VARRAY(4) OF NUMBER;
/
create table tarticulos(
   cod_art number(4) primary key,
   deno varchar2(15),
   pvp number(5),
   ventas total_trim
);
/
create table tventas(
   cod_art number(4) references tarticulos,
   fecha date,
   unidades number(4)
);
/
insert into tarticulos values (0001, 'articulo1', 50, total_trim(3,4,5,6));
insert into tarticulos values (0002, 'articulo2', 75, total_trim(2,7,3,9));

insert into tventas values (0001, '1/1/2012', 100);
insert into tventas values (0001, '2/2/2012', 10);
insert into tventas values (0001, '10/10/2012', 30);
insert into tventas values (0002, '6/6/2012', 200);
insert into tventas values (0002, '6/6/2012', 40);
insert into tventas values (0002, '12/12/2012', 50);

declare
   cursor c2 is 
      select cod_art, to_number(to_char(fecha, 'q')) fech, sum(unidades) suma 
      from tventas  
      group by cod_art, to_number(to_char(fecha, 'q'))
      order by cod_art;
begin                                                                                            
   for i in c2 loop
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.fech);
   end loop;
end; 





Error que empieza en la línea: 26 del comando :
declare
cursor c2 is 
select cod_art, to_number(to_char(fecha, 'q')) fech, sum(unidades) suma 
from tventas  
group by cod_art, to_number(to_char(fecha, 'q'))
order by cod_art;
begin                                                                                            
for i in c2 loop
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.fech);
end loop;
end;

    Informe de error -
    ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
    ORA-06512: at line 3
    ORA-06512: at line 8
    00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:
```

This is the exact code of my whole session and what it throws when i run it.
I am sorry about mistakes, also in spelling, but it is the first time I ask a question here and I am not native english speaker.

Comment: You are doing really well for a first-time poster; many posters even after several years on this site have never posted testable code. Now to the code you posted: I just tested it and it works fine, it produces the expected result. The query looks correct, too. The only issue I ran into is with the INSERT statements. You have a date column into which you insert strings like '12/12/2012'. This relies on my NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting, which is not 'mm/dd/yyyy' so the INSERT failed. I changed my NLS setting, then it worked; but you shouldn't write INSERT like that, use TO_DATE() or date literals.

Comment: I copied your test setup to your question (though without the parent table and varray type as it doesn't seem to be related to the error - do put it back in if it is.) You can delete this answer as it is not an answer. It still works for me though.